# twitter image thumbnail in tweet

Tags: twitter

How to show images in twitter like instagram does ? what are the metatags twitter tries to find in the page to show as image thumbnail ? like when a twitpic or instagram link is provided .

like this example[image: twitter post example]

Comment: This question isn't very clear. Could you explain more? Perhaps show us what you've tried? You might want to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) around what makes a good question - and also why it's important accept answers!

Comment: I added the image but it's not appearing .

Answer (score 2):

I use http://embed.ly/

You can use the service to create a regex of all the image services, find those links, pass them to Embed.ly and get an image thumbnail back.

You can write a simple set of regular expressions for the most common service, here's one which I use.

```
'#youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([_-\d\w]+)#i' => 'http://i.ytimg.com/vi/%s/1.jpg',
'#youtu\.be\/([_-\d\w]+)#i'             => 'http://i.ytimg.com/vi/%s/1.jpg',
'#qik\.ly\/([_-\d\w]+)#i'                       => 'http://qik.ly/%s.jpg',
'#twitpic\.com\/([\d\w]+)#i'            => 'http://twitpic.com/show/thumb/%s',
'#twitgoo\.com\/([\d\w]+)#i'            => 'http://twitgoo.com/show/thumb/%s',
'#hellotxt\.com\/i\/([\d\w]+)#i'        => 'http://hellotxt.com/image/%s.s.jpg',
'#ts1\.in\/(\d+)#i'                         => 'http://ts1.in/mini/%s',
'#moby\.to\/\?([\w\d]+)#i'                      => 'http://moby.to/%s:square',
'#mobypicture\.com\/\?([\w\d]+)#i'          => 'http://mobypicture.com/?%s:square',
'#twic\.li\/photo\/([\w]+)#i'           => 'http://twic.li/userimg/thumb_%s.jpg',
'#tweetphoto\.com\/(\d+)#'                      => 'http://api.plixi.com/api/tpapi.svc/imagefromurl?url=http://tweetp$
'#plixi\.com\/p\/(\d+)#'            => 'http://api.plixi.com/api/tpapi.svc/imagefromurl?url=http://plixi.$
'#phz\.in\/([\d\w]+)#'              => 'http://api.phreadz.com/thumb/%s?t=code',
'#imgur\.com\/([\w]{5})[\s\.ls][\.\w]*#i' => 'http://imgur.com/%ss.png',
'#imgur\.com\/gallery\/([\w]+)#i'           => 'http://imgur.com/%ss.png',
'#brizzly\.com\/pic\/([\w]+)#i'             => 'http://pics.brizzly.com/thumb_sm_%s.jpg',
'#img\.ly\/([\w\d]+)#i'             => 'http://img.ly/show/thumb/%s',
'#picplz\.com\/([\d\w\.]+)#'            => 'http://picplz.com/%s/thumb',
'#pk\.gd\/([\d\w]+)#i'              => 'http://img.pikchur.com/pic_%s_s.jpg',
'#pikchur\.com\/([\d\w]+)#i'            => 'http://img.pikchur.com/pic_%s_s.jpg',
'#znl\.me\/([\d\w]+)#'              => 'http://www.zannel.com/webservices/content/%s/Image-164x123-JPG.jp$
'#yfrog\.com\/([\d\w]+)#'                       => 'http://yfrog.com/%s:small',
'#instagr\.am\/p\/([_-\d\w]+)#i'        => 'http://instagr.am/p/%s/media/?size=t',
'#instagram\.com\/p\/([_-\d\w]+)#i'         => 'http://instagr.am/p/%s/media/?size=t',
'#twitrpix.com/([\d\w]+)#i'                 => 'http://img.twitrpix.com/thumb/%s',
```

Comment: What's Facebook thumbnail service?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [twitter cards](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/photo) for this

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="photo" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@flickr" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Mountain sunset" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7334/11858349453_e3f18e5881_z.jpg" />
<meta name="twitter:url" content="https://www.flickr.com/photos/reza-sina/11858349453/" />
```

You can test your card on [twitter card validator](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator)

If you find any [robote.text](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) issue you can do as in [twitter documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/getting-started#crawling)